# How to create a 3rd party login that insert data to custom model which inherit loopback base models, using loopback-component-passport?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

When created a custom model extending the base model, the data is inserted into the **base model**, not to the **custom model**.

### server/

### server.js

```
passportConfigurator.init();

passportConfigurator.setupModels({
  userModel: app.models.customer,
  userIdentityModel: app.models.customerIdentity,
  userCredentialModel: app.models.customerCredential,
});
```

### model-config.json

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "../common/models",
      "./models",
      "./node_modules/loopback-component-passport/lib/models"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  },
  "customer": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": true
  },
  "accessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  },
  "customerCredential": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  },
  "customerIdentity": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  }
}
```

### common/models

customer.json

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "plural": "customers",
  "base": "User",
  "relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "accessToken",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    },
    "customeridentities": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "customerIdentity",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    },
    "customercredentials": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "customerCredential",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

### customer-credential.json

```
{
  "name": "customerCredential",
  "plural": "customerCredentials",
  "base": "UserCredential",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

### accessToken.json

```
{
  "name": "accessToken",
  "plural": "accessTokens",
  "base": "AccessToken",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

### customerIdentity.json

```
{
  "name": "customerIdentity",
  "plural": "customerIdentities",
  "base": "UserIdentity",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

This above is the configuration in code.

But in the database the table created were User and AccessToken not customer and accessToken.

When I remove the user and access token from the model-config.json.

```
"User": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDb",
    "public": false
  }
```

The customer table and accessToken table (custom tables) were created in the mongo database.
But I get the following error message in console.

Error Message

---

The model "accessToken" configures "belongsTo User-like models" relation with target model "User". However, the model "User" is not attached to the application and therefore cannot be used by this relation. This typically happens when the application has a custom custom User subclass, but does not fix AccessToken relations to use this new model.
But when the User and AccessToken are added to the model-config the table created in the db is not the custom dbs customer and accessToken. Its the base data models User and AccessToken.

Comment: was UserIdendity or customerIdendity created ??

Comment: customerIdentity is created